# How to call a function passed as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

Is it possible to call a function which is passed as a parameter in Python? I have tried doing it, but it gives an error

Code:

```
def doStuff():
    print("doing stuff")

def doWork():
    print("doing work")

def call_function(func):
    func()

call_function(doStuff())
call_function(doWork())
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`call_function(doStuff())` means "use the value returned by `doStuff` as the argument to `call_function`". This is not what you want, you want to use the function `doStuff` itself as the argument.

To get the effect you want, omit the parentheses on the function you're passing as an argument: `call_function(doStuff)`

The key insight here is the distinction between the function itself and the value returned by the function. The function itself is an entity in python, like a string or a list or a dictionary, which has the property of being callable. (that is, it has a `__call__` method)
When you see a reference to a function followed by a matched pair of parentheses, either by name (as in `doStuff()`) or by alias (as in `func()`) or as a reference (as in `lambda x: x+1()`) that expression evaluates to the value returned by the function. This value is `None` unless the execution of the function hits a `return` statement, in which case the returned value is just the result of evaluating the expression following the `return`. The value returned by the function can be any legitimate python entity, including another function.

All of these words, which bear thinking about and possibly further experimentation or study on your part, allow me to say more simply that *`doStuff` is the name of a function, and `doStuff()` is an expression which triggers the execution of that function and evaluates to the returned value of that function*

Comment: Basically, he needs to pass a function into `call_function` not a value. But the `doStuff()` returns a value.

Comment: oh..I did not know that. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was just wondering if the function which has to be called needs a few arguments...how can we do that??

Comment: This is worth a new question. Short answer: when you have any reference to a function, you can call it with whatever arguments it needs.  However, there are interesting options if you want to go down the path of functional programming in python.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the `call_function` function should just pass the function name, not the function call, e.g. `call_function(doStuff)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def doStuff():
    print("doing stuff")

def doWork():
    print("doing work")

def call_function(func):
    func()

call_function(doStuff)
call_function(doWork)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, I find it's most helpful to explain the phenomenon in question, rather than simply providing the correct incantation.